# When I am update any field in parse database, I'm getting following error from parse database

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, afnetworking

Updating any field in parse database I'm getting below error very randomly,

My configuration in the AppDelegate looks like:

```
[Parse initializeWithConfiguration:[ParseClientConfiguration configurationWithBlock:^(id<ParseMutableClientConfiguration> configuration) {
    configuration.applicationId = @"wrWJqA47ZvZA27X26HsJzDxc5xxxxxxx";
    configuration.clientKey = @"hOhqpoIVK17joL6GiBGD54XIxxxxxx";
    configuration.server = @"https://parse.nightlifexp.com/parse";
}]];
```

You can see my code for updating parse database in the following link:-https://dpaste.de/Fhrk

The interesting thing is Parse.Cloud.beforeSave function works as expected.
Only when I requested data back, this issue appears very randomly.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

No proper solution found for this parse database error.
Anyone can help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message simply says that the JSON string is no JSON or is empty.

Comment: Thank u, but this JSON string is empty when i'm updating any value in parse database and it's occures very randomly. My question is what is the reason behind this error? and how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your JSON is not an array it has nothing to do with your Objective-c code , but the input from your server is wrong.
I think your solution should be on parse.com .

Comment: Thank you 0nder_ .

Comment: Just let me know when you solve your problem :) @Tapas_ios

Comment: But what should be modify for this in parse.com? I'm beginner in objective c so I have not so much knowledge about parse.com please help me how I can fix this issue?

Comment: beforeSave triggered for Request
Input: {"senderID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"I1NXR6TQU1"},"requestStatus":"pending","requestType":"friend_request","receiverID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"uFaVS4JeDt"}}
Result: {"object":{"senderID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"I1NXR6TQU1"},"requestStatus":"pending","requestType":"friend_request","receiverID":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"uFaVS4JeDt"}}}

This type of ERROR getting from parse database logs. Why i'm geeting this error and how to solve this error.